# Появление блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке равной 100% высоты экрана появлялся блок на js?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: используйте скрипт, который будет показывать (например, проставлять `display: block`) ваш блок после того, как scrollTop будет равен высоте вашего экрана

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Решение на `jQuery`:

```
   $(function() { 
      $(window).scroll(function() {
         $('.some-block')[$(this).scrollTop() >= $(this).height() ? 'show' : 'hide']();
       });
   });
```

Демо: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/redMgx

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Comment: Поставь отметку правильного ответа в таком случае )

Comment: @Invision это что за запись такая? `[$(this).scrollTop() >= $(window).height() ? 'show' : 'hide']()`

Comment: создает массив с одним значением из названия метода который необходимо исполнить в качестве функции

Answer (score 1):

Еще один примерчик на основе вышеуказанного

```js
$(function() {

  var w = $('.some-block').outerWidth();
  $('.some-block').css({
    right: -w
  });

  // INFO
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.info .window').text('Window height is ' + $(window).height() + 'px');
  }).resize();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // INFO
    $('.info .scroll').text('Scroll top: ' + $(window).scrollTop() + 'px');
    console.log('animate');


    // SHOW / HIDE BLOCK
    //$('.some-block')[$(window).scrollTop() >= $(window).height() ? 'show' : 'hide']();

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(window).height()) {
      $('.some-block').stop().animate({
        right: '0px'
      }, 100);
    } else {
      $('.some-block').stop().animate({
        right: -w
      }, 100);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  right: 0px;
}
.some-block {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <span class="window"></span>
  <br>
  <span class="scroll"></span>
</div>
<div class="some-block">SOME BLOCK IS VISIBLE</div>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
<h1>text</h1>
```